# NAN coming after Band Pass Filtering in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters

I have applied a Band Pass Filter having **cut-off frequencies [100 200] Hz and order 4 on a 10 sec signal (done in MATLAB)**. It is working fine. When I have increased the **order to 6**, though the filter has been designed but applying it to the same 10 sec signal, the filtered output is showing NAN. Can anyone help me out on this issue? And what is the reason for such behavior in filtering?

Comment: Instability. We don't know your filter coefficients, so that's all we can say.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Are the filter coefficients responsible for instability? I am using a simple 4th order Butterworth Band Pass Filter having cut-off frequencies [100 200] Hz.

Comment: please post the code and/or the filter coefficients

Comment: Welcome to SE.DSP!  As Marcus and Francesco say, there's no easy way for us to be completely sure without being able to see your filter's coefficients.  Please post the matlab steps, or the actual coefficients produced themselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, Marcus and Francesco for your help. I am posting here the coefficients.

Comment: 1. b_bpf =

   1.0e-05 *

    0.0613         0   -0.2451         0    0.3676         0   -0.2451         0    0.0613

Comment: a_bpf =

    1.0000   -7.8256   26.8187  -52.5709   64.4698  -50.6491   24.8939   -6.9984    0.8616

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include the coefficients. They are *central* to your question, and should not be hidden in the comments. I'll try to answer once you've done that.

Comment: (it would still be a good idea to also post the matlab code that *generated* these coefficients – I don't think you realize that the "cut off freqs 100, 200 Hz" is not a complete filter specification)